# How to qsub idl job on cluster?

Tags: idl, qsub

I'd like to use `qsub` to submit my `idl` job. But there were always errors. My script is as follows:

```
#####################################
#$ -S /bin/bash
##$ -j y
#$ -cwd
#$ -m e
### PE size must be a multiple of 12!
###$ -pe impi4 24
### wallclock up to 48 hours
#$ -l h_rt=48:00:00
#$ -M emailaddress
#$ -N 'name'
#$ -o 'name'
#$ -e 'name'
source ~/.bashrc
cd /mydirectory
echo "start time:"
date

idl -e .com file1
    -e file2
#####################################
```

I have to do `source .bashrc` first to make some library in `idl` work(for some reason I must do in this way). Then I need to first compile `file1` to make `file2` work smoothly, ie. in a normal terminal command line, I need to do `.com file1` then carriage return then `file2` with no `run` or anything. But here it doesn't work, the error says

```
idl command not found 

-e command not found
```

Why? I tried to add `\r` and `!c` behand `file1` and it seemed not working and delete the `-e` before `file2`, still not. I use `SuSe` os.

Thank you for @mgalloy 's advice, I do as you said

```
Pro program
   .compile file1
   file2
End
```

and got errors

```
Pro program
           ^   
% Programs can't be compiled from single statement mode.
  At: /directory/program.pro, Line 1
% Compiled module: xxx
several compiled steps
% Attempt to call undefined procedure: 'file2'.
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$    

End
 ^
% Syntax error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, your idl is not being found. I would just put a full path to it, e.g.,

```
/usr/local/exelis/idl/bin/idl
```

Secondly, and maybe thirdly, you can't have two "-e" arguments and you need quotes around a command with multiple words. So, I would put your IDL commands in a file, say my_program.pro:

```
.compile file1
file2
```

And then call it like this:

```
/usr/local/exelis/idl/bin/idl /full/path/to/my_program.pro
```

Note: no "-e" in the above, this is running the commands in a batch file, not executing an IDL statement.